# Why 'ABC'.replace('B', '$`') gives AAC

Tags: javascript, regex

Why this code prints `AAC` instead of expected `` A$`C ``?

```
console.log('ABC'.replace('B', '$`'));
```

==>

```
AAC
```

And how to make it give the expected result?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/leftContext but this is **non-standard** fdature

Comment: @anubhava: This feature is very much standard. The *property* described in the docs you were linking is non-standard.

Comment: Hmm not sure as it says: **`RegExp.$\`` is an alias for this property**

Comment: @anubhava: ``​RegExp.$`​`` property is non standard. ``​$`​`` in the replacement string is standard.

Comment: _follow-up question_: does anyone know why escaping the `$` with a backslash \\ doesn't produce the correct result (i.e. "\$`")?

Comment: @greenSocksRock Because for whatever reason it's escaped by a second `$` instead.

Comment: wrong expectations? AAC *is* the expected result.

Comment: @OllieFord Do you know for whatever reason it's escaped by a second $ instead?  (_hint:_ I'll be mildly disappointed if you don't reply with "Because.")

Comment: @greenSocksRock: I suspect it is probably because the replace support backreferences, you can read something about that here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html#replace

Comment: I think this question should be closed and I think this user should be prevented from asking his or her own questions. This is not a legitimate question, it's not a problem anyone has actually had. It's an attempt to farm reputation by asking about a piece of trivia and immediately answering it. Imagine if the asker duplicated this question with questions about `"$&"`, `"$'"` and `"$1"`. That would be a waste of space, and this is too. StackOverflow is not for trivia clearly answered in documentation.

Comment: @MilesRout, your assumption on farming is not true, I spent hours before I narrowed this down in my XML parser. I can send you github code link for proof, maybe you can even compare dates of commits and the question. And Exactly SO community pointed me to a right direction. In fact I thought this was v8 bug.

https://github.com/ksanaforge/tibetan/blob/master/sambotha.js

Comment: @MilesRout, you are right that reading documentation should have answered this, but when I hit the problem I was shocked and my first idea was to ask the community and it helped immediately.

Comment: Not because I've answered, but because of the fact that such a question didn't yet exist in SO I don't understand why it should be closed. There are tons of other questions where many persons farm reputation and I usually only answer where I don't see a related question which is similar or eventually a duplicate of the question I'm checking. In this case, I didn't really find any question similar to this one and, besides, despite reading the documentation would've helped, it isn't the very first thing the documentation tells you to be entirely honest.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

To insert a literal `$` you have to pass `$$`, because `` $` ``:

> Inserts the portion of the string that precedes the matched substring.

```js
console.log('ABC'.replace('B', "$$`"));
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Other patterns:

> | Pattern | Inserts |
> | --- | --- |
> | `$$` | Inserts a `$`. |
> | `$&` | Inserts the matched substring. |
> | `` $` `` | Inserts the portion of the string that precedes the matched substring. |
> | `$'` | Inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched substring. |
> | `$n` | Where *`n`* is a positive integer less than 100, inserts the _`n`_th parenthesized submatch string, provided the first argument was a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object. Note that this is `1`-indexed. If a group *`n`* is not present (e.g., if group is 3), it will be replaced as a literal (e.g., `$3`). |
> | `$<Name>` | Where *`Name`* is a capturing group name. If the group is not in the match, or not in the regular expression, or if a string was passed as the first argument to `replace` instead of a regular expression, this resolves to a literal (e.g., `$<Name>`). Only available in browser versions supporting named capturing groups. |

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kou1z3q/)

Also, there are even more things on the reference link I’ve posted above. If you still have any issue or doubt you probably can find an answer there, the screenshot above was taken from the link posted at the beginning of the answer.

It is worth saying, in my opinion, that *any* pattern that doesn’t match the above *doesn’t need to be escaped*, hence `$` doesn’t need to be escaped, same story happens with `$AAA`.

In the comments above a user asked about why you need to “escape” `$` with another `$`: despite I’m not truly sure about that, I think it is also worth to point out, from what we said above, that **any invalid pattern won’t be interpreted**, hence I think (and suspect, at this point) that `$$` is a very special case, because it covers the cases where you need to replace the match with a dollar sign followed by a “pattern-locked” character, like the tick (`` ` ``) as an example (or really the `&` as another).

In any other case, though, the dollar sign **doesn’t need to be escaped**, hence it probably makes sense that they decided to create such a specific rule, else you would’ve needed to escape the `$` everywhere else (and I think this could’ve had an impact on any string object, because that would mean that even in `var a = "hello, $ hey this one is a dollar";`, you would’ve needed to escape the `$`).

If you’re still interested and want to read more, please also check [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html#replace) and this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kou1z3q/3/) with more cases.

Answer (score 46):

In the `replacement` the `$` dollar sign has a special meaning and is used when data from the match should be used in the `replacement`.

[MDN: String.prototype.replace(): Specifying a string as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)

> $$   Inserts a "$".
>    $`   Inserts the portion of the string that precedes the matched substring.

As long as the `$` does not result in a combination that has a special meaning, then it will be just handled as a regular char. But you should still always write it as a `$$` in the replacement because otherwise, it might fail in future if a new `$x` combination is added.

Comment: $ sign alone does not cause this behaviour, only dollar+back tick combination

Comment: @exebook sure on it's own it won't be a problem. But still the `$` has a special meaning. Similar to the `-`  (differnce between `[a-f]` and `[af-]` )